# Java MVC Web development framework?

Tags: java, ajax, model-view-controller, frameworks

I want to develop a website with java but I'm absolute beginner in java web development.

I want to use a framework that uses the MVC pattern and Ajax.

I did some search and found that Spring or Struts are suitable but I'm not sure.

could you please recommend a framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend Spring:

[Developing a Spring Framework MVC application step-by-step](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/)

Answer (score 8):

[Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org/) might be a good option because of its incredible simplicity.

Comment: +1 play is far better than spring mvc and other java web frameworks

Comment: Yip! It doesn't need a plethora of XML files; comes bundled with a server which reloads all modified files automatically (very useful while developing); was the single framework that beat the others BY FAR in terms of coding productivity for me; Has a command-line tool for creating new projects, installing addons, running projects, generating project files for different IDE's, etc etc. Error reports on your dev site include breakdowns all the way down to the line of code. Scala and Scalate support is in progress. It astounds me that people still prefer the bloated frameworks (like Spring).

Answer (score 1):

The Stripes Framework is also worth consideration and can be used along with Spring.
http://www.stripesframework.org

It's easy to use and easy to configure.  Unlike Struts, which is fairly old hat these days.


There are a plethora of frameworks now and it's worth checking each one that will suit your needs.  It's a personal thing and it's good that we're not all restricted to a few.

Answer (score 1):

[JRapid](http://www.jrapid.com) is very easy to use. You'll get a working application in minutes and it generates AJAX powered user interface.

Answer (score 0):

I work with Spring Webflow - technology based on Spring MVC. Webflow is described in official help pretty well. Personally, it think Webflow is much more usable than bare Spring MVC, however there are always someone who disagrees.
Moreover Spring (not talking about MVC specifically) can be used outside of web projects, so it seems to me it is advantage of Spring.
Cannot say anything about Struts.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend GRAILS for fast rapid web application development, that includes scaffolding functionality and web page generation based on data models.

https://grails.org/learn

It is the fastest way for MVC developers.