# How Does Play compare to Stripes

Tags: playframework, stripes

Hi has anyone had any experience using both Stripes and Play and can compare their strengths and weaknesses?
I understand there are many similar questions such as [Stripes, Spring, Play (or ?) : which high performance Java framework to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633336/stripes-spring-play-or-which-high-performance-java-framework-to-use) however I haven't found anmy direct comparisons.

For my part we used Stripes in a fairly complex application last year and were very happy with it however the fact that the community seems so small and relatively quiet is a bit concerning for me going forward.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The community of Play! is extremely active and it's growing very fast. I don't have a lot of experience with Stripes but I enjoyed it, especially after coming of 7 years of Spring/Hibernate in a very large application (huge spring context, about 500 Hibernate entities, a couple of thousand Spring beans, almost 5mins startup time. But Play! is extremely productive and to me that's the main difference, it makes the easy things very easy, it makes the very hard things very possible. Their http async support is extremely elegant, their hibernate layer just works, WebSockets support is a breeze and the list goes on and on. It's just such a fun framework!

I have a couple of sites I post a lot of information on Play!
http://geeks.aretotally.in/
http://playframework.info/

Hope this helps.

Thank you,
Felipe

Answer (score -1):

I don’t think the size of the Stripes community is that much different of the Play community. For example here at Stackoverflow the [Play framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/playframework) has 160 followers against 60 [Stripe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stripes)s followers.

If a bigger community is the criteria you might want to consider other action based frameworks like [Struts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/struts) (355 followers) and [Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-mvc) (620 followers and 2300 on the more general [Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring) tag).